# The C# tag clips just a tad

Tags: bug, design

The picture is pretty self explanatory. It seems that the `#` sign on the [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) clips when formatted into a tag. C# and `C#` don't do it, but [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) does.

[image: Tag clipping]

Comment: No big deal, just refill the ink cartridges and you'll be fine

Comment: What OS and browser are you using? It renders fine for me.

Comment: @200_success That's Google chrome on Windows 8.1.

Comment: @200_success  using firefox same problem

Comment: Google Chrome on Linux is giving the same problem.

Comment: Same here with Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: @200_success What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: Safari and Firefox on OS X look OK.